# change font colour in textbox with CSS when value is typed into box

Tags: html, forms, css, textbox

I have a text box, which acts as a search box on my page. I pre-populate the field with the word 'SEARCH' which has a default text colour of #D6D6D0.

Using CSS, is it possible to change the text colour to #FFFFFF when someone enters text in the box?

```
<input type="text" name="q" value="SEARCH" id="searchFieldText">

#searchFieldText {
    background: url("/images/crmpicco/search_bg3.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border: medium none;
    color: #D6D6D0;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 21px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 168px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The focus pseudo class should work

```
#searchFieldText:focus {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `:focus` will only apply when the box is currently in focus, when the user comes out of the text box the color will revert.

I would suggest using the `placeholder` attribute, override the styling for the `placeholder` to be the `#D6D6D0` color you wanted and apply the style you want on the textbox.

You can override the `placeholder` styling with these psuedo selectors:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:    #D6D6D0;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    color:    #D6D6D0;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    color:    #D6D6D0;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color:    #D6D6D0;
}
```

I made a fiddle that gives you an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/bM5AE/

Answer (score 4):

You can better use placeholder to pre-populate fields, on typing they will be gone, if onblur the field is empty the placeholder comes back.

```
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="SEARCH" id="searchFieldText">
```

And if you wan't to style the placeholder

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: red;  
}
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: red;  
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
  color: red;  
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UYFNf/)

Comment: 1) they won't be gone on focus but on typing the first letter 2) it's support is not very nice, <=IE9 does not support it.

Comment: 1) true ;) 2) '<=IE9-people' are crazy and are holding back innovations. If we always have to support older browsers we will never get rid of them...

Comment: sry, but that's nonsense - IE9 is the most recent browser you can get on Vista & Windows 7 (and IE8 for WinXP). If you are doing serious webdevelopment, you cannot ignore support for this browser(s).

Comment: i was exaggerating, because it's sometimes very frustrating with all the different browsers going around

Comment: that's true, especially with IE practically being the only one to stall the development of the web :-/ Sometimes I'm dreaming the webdeveloper's dream of a world with only one browser supporting all the standards without any bugs :-D

Answer (score 1):

Using the pseudoclass `:focus` will do the trick for you.

```
#searchFieldText:focus{
    color:#fff;   
}
```

I also recommend you to use the new attribute `placeholder` for the input field which will do some magic for you (need to be aware of support however).

[See the example](http://jsfiddle.net/ukxAw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

hi Try the below code it will work....

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#searchFieldText").keypress(function () {
                $("#searchFieldText").css("color", "#ffffff");
            });
        });
```